# Managing Python versions with environment-modules

Tags: redhat, python, rhel6, environment-variables

I'm trying to configure a RHEL6 server to allow multiple users to run multiple versions of Python, multiple versions of various python modules, and multiple versions of various other programs (e.g. gcc). I believe the appropriate way to do this is to use environment-modules and virtualenv. I'm familiar with virtualenv, but I'm confused about using environment-modules.

I installed Python 2.7.3 with:

```
# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local
# make && make altinstall
```

and I can easily enough run Python 2.7.3 with:

```
/usr/local/python-2.7
```

I thought I could simply use my module file to preprend my `PATH` environment variable with `/usr/local/python-2.7` but there is not `python` binary in `/usr/local/python-2.7`, only a binary called `python-2.7`.

Am I missing something? How do I use an environment-modules module file to use Python 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run it using `/usr/local/python-2.7` then the directory to include in your `PATH` would be `/usr/local` which is undesirable.

You should do something like this:

```
rm /usr/local/python-2.7
mkdir -p /usr/local/python-2.7
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python-2.7
make && make altinstall
```

Then you can do:

```
PATH=/usr/local/python-2.7:$PATH
```

or the `environment-modules` equivalent. Then it can be run without specifying the directory:

```
python-2.7
```

In order to run it directly, then, you'd do this:

```
/usr/local/python-2.7/python-2.7
```

Comment: I see, I just needed to push the Python install in one more directory. I'll give it a shot now. Thanks.

Comment: Still had to add a `python -> python-2.7` softlink, but now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at VirtualEnv, it's a python tool made to do address exactly what you're looking for.

[Python - VirtualEnv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Comment: Sure, virtualenv does what I need _inside_ Python as mentioned in the question, but I'm talking about multiple versions of Python (and gcc, other misc tools) on the same server, which is what environment-modules is for. It's confusing because Python uses 'modules' and virtualenv lets you manage different versions of python modules, but environment-modules also uses 'modules' to manage different versions of applications and is entirely unrelated to python modules.

Comment: If I correctly understand your needs, it more than just the python environment that you need to look at but rather a system-wide solution like Docker https://www.docker.io, let me know if my assumption is correct.

Comment: Docker does look interesting, I'll keep an eye on it

Comment: @DylanHettinger, yeah, its a new way to work with old tools named LXC, it is mostly a high level unified command liner and APIs for LXC indeed with some really interesting implements for Chief/Puppet Master and Heath OpenStack Orchestrators.
If you're looking for a WebAdmin dashboard, there is Shipyard that I like :D